# Actually erasing a commit from a remote Git repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to know if there's a way to **actually** delete a commit from a remote Git repository. I have committed (and pushed) sensitive data, so I used the obvious

```
git reset HEAD^
git push -f
```

To rewrite the branch with what was there before, but if I try to access the former commit's page (on GitLab) using its hash, I still see its contents (even if it's referenced nowhere).

I tried running "housekeeping" (which to my understanding should remove this) but it didn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: It will eventually be garbage collected, depending on your repo's settings. Are you concerned that it would be accessed in the meantime? How other than by commit hash would it be?

Comment: Well, uniquely by commit hash but with CI / CD it might already have leaked in some logs

Comment: If the commit hash is out, all its contents are already spilled out, anyone could cat-file it to read its contents.

Comment: Same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/resetting-remote-to-a-certain-commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally committed sensitive information - GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560337/accidentally-committed-sensitive-information-gitlab)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab%5D+remove+sensitive+data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remove+sensitive+data